# get contents of URL like facebook wall post

Tags: php, facebook, joomla

i'm using obsocial submit to submit articles from joomla to facebook. It publishes just one line with a link to the article.

In facebook, when you paste or tyep a url, it automatically extracts the contents from the url with images if any.

Is there api available that i can use to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you abit

```
<?php
$site = file_get_contents ($url);

$meta = get_meta_tags ($url);
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $site, $result); 
preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/s', $temp, $title);
?>
```

Comment: well get_meta_tags gathers all the meta tags from the page given in $url.

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $site, $result); collects all images on the page

preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/s', $temp, $title); picks up the title

don' think you need anything more

Comment: you can't :-( ... and you have to write enough to comment

Comment: +1, I would basically do the same, except for the images and title extraction, I would use a DOM and getElementsByTagName solution over a Regex based one, safer.

Answer (score 3):

I found [jquery liveUrl](https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl) helpful for a similar usecase
[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srikpreethy/xj4m8ptn/)

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" placeholder="write here"></textarea>
$('textarea').liveUrl({
                        success : function(data) 
                        {
    console.log(data);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a class/api which provide such functionality. But it is not to hard to write your own.

You can use [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) to grep all metatags of a certain page und filter for the graph tags. if they are present you have won. if not, you would have to parse the  of the page to find the content by yourself. (see @Jobbdirekt Krostofer'S answer)

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ for the Graph Meta Tags.

EDIT: Found a php class for parsing for graph meta tags: 
http://buzzword.org.uk/2010/opengraph/#php